# What will we be doing about wrong reviews?

Tags: discussion, post-review

Reputation awarded for a question was raised from 5 to 10 recently. As a result, many users earned privileges overnight. Some started to attend reviews also.

But when users do not know the scope of the question completely and participate in reviews, it will give rise to inaccurate reviews which are not inline with our meta discussions and help center. This is not against any specific user(s). This is something I have noticed from multiple users. I saw many "Leave Open" in the reviews even though the questions were fit for closure.

I understand there is some kind of  difference in opinion in exact duplicates. We can put them aside for now. But questions which ask about Sanskrit language and Programming, transliteration of verses, many questions under one post are also left open. (Needless to say all these are closeable as off-topic and "Needs focus").

[image: Screenshot of a review queue]

Above is a screenshot of review history. Such reviews have not stopped even now. There are reviews based on personal opinion.

The scope of our site and help center are clear what is on-topic and what is not. A review is not a subjective decision and not dependent on personal opinion. For example if a user asks about Devanagari script and its transliteration, there is no scope of opinion difference, the question should be closed as off-topic. If the user is not sure what should be the action on a question, they may click "Skip" but "Leave Open" is being selected for questions which should be closed.

As a result, a question which is supposed to be closed will stay open because it received enough reviews to stay open. Close votes cast on the question start to expire. This causes delay in moderation.

As a community, what steps should we take so that users participating in the reviews give accurate reviews? What action will be taken by the moderators to correct a wrong review?

Comment: Should we move this question to meta SE instead? Because I feel this issue is not specific to Hinduism SE but across SE sites?

Comment: Meanwhile, link wrong reviews in chat-room so that we can correct them if required.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā See this link and correct the reviews which are wrong. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/close/history

Comment: Question: What should we do about what His Majesty thinks are wrong reviews? Answer: We should give His Majesty five close votes so that His Majesty has absolute powers to close any question.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion Just remember your name and follow it, that is enough.

Comment: Weak on sarcasm, aren't you?

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion If you think so, you don't know me.

Comment: The best way out to this peculiar situation is to transfer all the rights to Moderators.  As many of the members, including me, may not be aware of all rules for conducting a review @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Moderators already have the power to close questions.

Comment: As he is feeling that some of the members got privileges prematurely, and that those members could not utilise those privileges properly, I had commented so.  Anyways, some of the seniors and moderators of this site are already having **their own way** of functioning, irrespective of the damage caused to the site, in the form of many members being silenced morally.  So it doesn't make difference to me even if the newly handed over pre-matured privileges, as expressed by him, are withdrawn or remained with me. @I will close your question

Comment: @iwill lol you again started behaving like.. I don't know what should I call? Lack of knowledge of SE or what? If you don't know what a review is or how to review then please stop doing. That would be of great help.